# why does the compiler give error on the following haskell code?

Tags: class, haskell, instance

I am trying to study the type classes in haskell. I write the following script and the raised an error. I am unable to understand why the compiler thinks of v as an concrete type while it is just a parameter for class Boxer.

```
data Box1 a b = Box1 Double a [b]

class Boxer v where
  foo :: (v a b) -> Double

instance Boxer (Box1 a b) where
  foo (Box1 r s t) = r
```

it raises an error in line 7:8:

```
Couldn't match type `v' with `Box1'
  `v' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for foo :: v a b -> Double at file1.hs:4:10
Expected type: v a b
  Actual type: Box1 a b
Relevant bindings include
  foo :: v a b -> Double (bound at file1.hs:7:3)
In the pattern: Box1 r s t
In an equation for `foo': foo (Box1 r s t) = r
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: In this case the error is probably due to indentation - the `foo` declaration is not associated with the `Boxer` class, so it expects a function of type `forall v a b . v a b -> Double`. Besides that, `instance Boxer (Box1 a b)` is incorrect - it should be `instance Boxer Box1`. The former would be a type error if the `foo` function was correctly associated with the `Boxer` class.

Comment: @user2407038 thank you very much. It was indeed an error due to indentation.

But could you please explain, when I create an instance of Foldable, there the compiler does not let me do instance Foldable Box1. It asks to put more parameters on Box1.

Comment: You will have to write `instance Foldable (Box1 a)` - the `Foldable` class takes a parameter of kind `* -> *` whereas the kind of `Box1` is `* -> * -> *`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particular problem was being caused by improper indentation. Though there was another thing I was doing wrong. So the following version compiled:

```
data Box1 a b = Box1 Double a [b]

class Boxer v where
  foo :: (v a b) -> Double

instance Boxer Box1 where
  foo (Box1 r s t) = r
```

Answer (score 2):

In your instance, the compiler has to instantiate `v` with `Box1 a b`. In particular, it has to instantiate `v a b` with something like `(Box1 a b) a b` – except both `a` variables come from a different place; they're actually disambiguated to `(Box1 a b) a1 b1`. Which is the same as `Box1 a b a1 b1`.

```
foo :: Box1 a b a1 b1 -> Double
```

Does that make any sense?

The problem is that you're confusing a *(type) function*, namely `Box1`, with the *result* of applying said function to some type arguments. The *kinds* don't match:

```
GHCi> :k Boxer
Boxer :: (* -> * -> *) -> Constraint
GHCi> :k (Box1 Int String)
Box1 Int String :: *
```

`* -> * -> *` is the kind of a type function / type constructor with two arguments, so that's what `Boxer` needs. Whereas `Box1 a b` is simply a type, with no arguments. Doesn't match! OTOH,

```
GHCi> :k Box1
Box1 :: * -> * -> *
```

Comment: This addresses a semantic error in the code, but the type error in the OP is due to the incorrect indentation in the original code.